# How can I query mongodb using mongoid/rails without timing out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a rake task that processes a set of records and saves it in 
another collection:

```
batch = [] 

Record.where(:type => 'a').each do |r| 
  batch <<  make_score(r)

  if batch.size %100 == 0 
    Score.collection.insert(batch) 
    batch = [] 
  end 
end
```

I'm processing about 100K records at a time. Unfortunately at 20 minutes, I get a `Query response returned CURSOR_NOT_FOUND` error.

The mongodb [faq](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Frequently+Asked+Questions+-+Ruby#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Ruby-IkeepgettingCURSORNOTFOUNDexceptions.What%27shappening%3F) says to use `skip` and `limit` or turn off timeouts, using them the all thing was about ~2-3 times slower.

How can I turn off timeouts in conjunction with mongoid?

Comment: FYI, there's an `each_slice` method in ruby: `Record.where(type: 'a').each_slice(100){|batch| Score.collection.insert(batch)}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [MongoDB docs](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html) say you can pass in a timeout boolean, and it timeout is false, it will never timeout

```
collection.find({"type" => "a"}, {:timeout=>false})
```

In your case:

```
Record.collection.find({:type=>'a'}, :timeout => false).each ...
```

I also recommend you look into map-reduced with Mongo. It seems tailer made to this sort of collection array manipulation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

Comment: Is it possible to perform the timeout option using Mongoid and not the javascript console? My query needs to be called from a Rails application.

Comment: yes, mongoid will send extra parameters to mongodb, so go for it

Comment: Alas there is a bug with Mongoid and disabling timeout it seems. Should be aware of it https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1847

Comment: @JesseWolgamott your code will not work using the official Ruby driver for MongoDB. `timeout: false` requires a block argument to prevent cursor leaks. The driver had a bug that would still leak that connection in the case of an exception but I submitted a patch and it is fixed now: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/pull/117

Answer (score 8):

In mongoid 3 you can use this:

```
ModelName.all.no_timeout.each do |m|
   "do something with model"
end
```

Which is pretty handy.

Answer (score 6):

It does seem, for now at least, you have to go the long route and query via the Mongo driver:

```
Mongoid.database[collection.name].find({ a_query }, { :timeout => false }) do |cursor| 
  cursor.each do |row| 
    do_stuff 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Yup rails 3.2 and mongoid 2.4.3 this is still the case. The Email.collection.find doesn't work the same as Email.db[Email.collection.name].find

Comment: This is the correct answer. `timeout: false` requires a block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround I did. Create an array to hold the full records, and work from that array like this

```
products = []

Product.all.each do |p|
products << p
end

products.each do |p|
# Do your magic
end
```

dumping all records into the array will most likely finish within before the timeout, unless you are working on extremely large number of records. Also, this is going to consume too much memory in case you are dealing with large or too many records as well, so keep in that mind.

Comment: Guarav Shah: As I pointed out, it consumes too much memory. If memory is an issue you can set incremental variable and loop over say 100 records at a time. Or use the :timeout => false per query I didn't know about before, if you're sure of your program