# Another way to say User.all.each_with_index?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I can't figure out why, but this loop is tumbling on one of the users

```
User.all.each_with_index do |user, i|
```

even if I just do this loop to print e-mails, I get:

```
MONGODB cursor.refresh() for cursor xxx
```

When I add more computations to this, it becomes fatal:

```
MONGODB cursor.refresh() for cursor yyy
rake aborted!
Query response returned CURSOR_NOT_FOUND. Either an invalid cursor was specified
```

What do you think might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a long running loop then its possible that the cursor is timing out. MongoDB cursors time out after 10 minutes by default. See:

https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/e532dbefce643531

[How can I query mongodb using mongoid/rails without timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018838/how-can-i-query-mongodb-using-mongoid-rails-without-timing-out)

Comment: Yes, looks like it runs out of memory, need to refactor