# Can I set Mongoid query timeout? Mongoid don't kill long time query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongodb-query

Mongoid don't have timeout option.
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html

I want Mongoid to kill long time queries.
How can I set Mongoid query timeout?

If I do nothing, Mongoid wait a long time like the below.

```
mongo > db.currentOp()

{
    "opid" : 34973,
    "active" : true,
    "secs_running" : 1317, // <- too long!
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "db_name.collection_name",
    "query" : {
    "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
  },
    "client" : "123.456.789.123:46529",
    "desc" : "conn42",
    "threadId" : "0x7ff5fb95c700",
    "connectionId" : 42,
    "locks" : {
    "^db_name" : "R"
  },
    "waitingForLock" : true,
    "numYields" : 431282,
    "lockStats" : {
    "timeLockedMicros" : {
     "r" : NumberLong(514304267),
     "w" : NumberLong(0)
  },
    "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
     "r" : NumberLong(1315865170),
     "w" : NumberLong(0)
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all queries have a timeout by default. You can set a `no_timeout` option to tell the query to never timeout.Take a look [here](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/options.html)

You can configure the timeout period using a initializer, like this

```
Mongoid.configure do |config|
  config.master = Mongo::Connection.new(
    "localhost", 27017, :op_timeout => 3, :connect_timeout => 3
  ).db("mongoid_database")
end
```

Comment: I want to set op_timeout and connect_timeout in config/mongoid.yml. And I've done so. But I couldn't confirm the params are valid or not. Where can I confirm the params are valid? CollectionName.all.options was empty hash.

Comment: @TerukiShinohara it does work and they are valid - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/UhRfszA_bd4

Answer (score 1):

The default query timeout is typically 60 seconds for Mongoids but due to Rubys threading there tend to be issues when it comes to shutting down processes properly.

Hopefully none of your requests will be putting that strain on the Mongrels but if you keep running into this issue I would consider some optimization changes to your application or possibly consider adopting God or Monit. If you aren't into that and want to change your request handing I might recommend Unicorn if you are already on nginx (github has made this transition and you can read about it more [here](https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn))

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
ModelName.all.no_timeout.each do |m|
  "do something with model"
end
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19987744/706022