# Mongo query timeout in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, moped

How do I set timeouts for my Mongo queries in Mongoid?
I know Mongo supports `cursor.maxTimeMS()` but could not find it in Mongoid documentation.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962254/can-i-set-mongoid-query-timeout-mongoid-dont-kill-long-time-query

Answer (score 0):

As of Mongoid 6, you can use something like this:

```
Model.max_time_ms(5000).all
```